# Need to get real path to the Servlet i'm using. JAVA

Tags: servlets

I need to get path to the servlet that i'm using inside of it. With some searchings i found something like this:

```
System.out.println(getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));
```

and the result is:

```
C:\Users\me\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\ProjectName\ServletName
```

tbh i dont know what does ".metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps" mean, i just want to get path to the "original" project which is:

```
C:\Users\me\workspace\ProjectName\ServletName
```

is there any way to get this path directly(without getting the big path first and then cutting the middle part of it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get is the location of the servlet *.class* file. Eclipse deploy your application in your server applications folder **.metadata/.plugins/.../wtpwebapps** (because you use the temporary folder which is different from your real Tomcat location), after invoking the function `getRealPath("/")`, your servlet has been deployed in the server and it has not been executed from it's original location. Even if you change tomcat's directory, you'll always get the location of the deployed servlet and not the *.java* file.
[read more about Server temporary location](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/where-is-eclipse-deploy-web-application-tomcat/).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`.This command point the root folder of the project.